# Persisting Checkbox State Across Postbacks

Tags: asp.net

I have a web form that binds a DataGrid to a, normally, different data source on each postback.  I have a static CheckBox column that is always present to the left of the autogenerated columns.  I achieve a TabControl effect with a horizontal Menu control above the grid, with each menu item being a tab that contains a different grid.

Now I would like to persist the state of these checkboxes for a particular 'tab', when another tab is selected.  I would welcome any imaginative solution for doing this without using session variables.

Comment: Nice question.  I don't have a ready answer but I suspect you will need to store the values in Session or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best bet for this is to have a different gridview for each of your "tabs". Use the MultiView control with a View control for each tab, and a gridview in each View. In the click event of your menu change to the correct view. Only bind each gridview once, and then your checkboxes will persist.

Comment: Thanks, that was my preferred solution, until it slowed things down too much.  I've gone on to using session state for now, but will check out the MultiView later.